# Visual Studio does not run all the unit tests in a test class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

I have 3 test methods in my unit test class, but Visual Studio only runs the second test, ignoring the others

These are the 3 test methods:

```
[TestClass()]
public class InsertionSortTest
{

    [TestMethod()]
    public void sortTest()
    {
        InsertionSort target = new InsertionSort(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int[] n = new int[] { 2, 1, 4 };
        int[] nExpected = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
        target.sort(ref n);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(nExpected, n);

    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void sortTest2()
    {
        InsertionSort target = new InsertionSort(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int[] n = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        int[] nExpected = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        target.sort(ref n);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(nExpected, n);

    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void sortTest3()
    {
        InsertionSort target = new InsertionSort(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int[] n = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        int[] nExpected = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        target.sort(ref n);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(nExpected, n);

    }
}
```

So when I run the test only sortTest2 is executed? I am expecting 3 results from this. I am getting Results 1/1 passed. TestName: sortTest2.

What happened with the other two tests I made?

Comment: Sounds like it's just running an old compilation or something like that... Try cleaning the cache an rerunning the tests

Comment: As an aside, please follow .NET naming conventions - and name your test methods so it's clear what scenario they're sorting. (You probably don't need `ref`, either...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gillyb, yeah, you where right I think. Re-starting Visual Studio fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have noticed tests being shown as "not run" after test run completed. Turned out these tests were never completed due to a StackOverflowException being thrown mid way.

Answer (score 1):

Something that has bitten me more than once with this is that the test project was not checked to be built in the solution configuration.